# typo3 4.6: get related models based on workspace

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

I have two tables, two models and two repositories.

1. Sections
2. Faqs

Faqs belong in sections (**one** section **has many** faqs). This relationship is done by storing the section uid in the faq.

In my templates i'm doing:

```
    <f:for each="{section.faqs}" as="faq">
        <h3 class="question"><a href="#"><f:format.html>{faq.question}</f:format.html></a></h3>
    </f:for>
```

Which displays the faqs in that section.

This works as expected on the front end as a normal user.

However, when i preview the page in the DRAFT workspace. Any draft faq questions are not displayed. I can only see faqs that are in the live workspace. I can however, see sections from the draft workspace.

Something is wrong in the relationship between faqs and sections.

How do i display the faqs in draft workspace sections?

Comment: You should ask on the mailing list whether workspaces are supported for nested objects in 4.6.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but maybe *workspace versioning* is not enabled in ext_tables.php: 
Check the settings for your faq table

```
$TCA['tx_yourextensioncode_faq'] = array (
    'ctrl' => array ( 
        ...
        'versioningWS' => TRUE,
        'versioning_followPages' => TRUE,
        'origUid' => 't3_origuid',
    ),
);
```

Or vice versa - maybe you have to disable it. 
ext_tables.php or Tca.php schould be the place to check.

Answer (score 0):

no way, workspaces and extbase don't go together in 4.6. Extbase comes with very basic and mainly faulty workspace support and anything which is somehow related to versioning of related objects will break. Same for TYPO3 4.7 and most likely also for the upcoming 6.0